# Perform Math per Column in CSV using Column Values

Tags: powershell, csv, math

I'm attempting to use PowerShell to pickup a CSV file, subtract value of one column from another and put it in a third, then print the CSV to default printer.

I've got everything working except the math. It imports, sets up my headers, and prints. However it doesn't seem to execute my `foreach` to do the math. It runs without errors though.

```
$hhsignscsv = Import-Csv -Header ("PLU","Description","Quantity","Price","FreqShopType","FreqShopValue","FreqShopPrice","LabelFormat","LabelQTY","SizeMeasurement","Limit") -Path hhsignsmod.csv
foreach ($hhsigns in $hhsignscsv) {
  $PLU = $hhsigns.PLU
  $Description = $hhsigns.Description
  $Quantity = $hhsigns.Quantity
  $Price = $hhsigns.Price
  $FreqShopType = $hhsigns.FreqShopType
  $FreqShopValue = $hhsigns.FreqShopValue
  $FreqShopPrice = $hhsigns.FreqShopPrice
  $LabelFormat = $hhsigns.LabelFormat
  $LabelQTY = $hhsigns.LabelQTY
  $SizeMeasurement = $hhsigns.SizeMeasurement
  $Limit = $hhsigns.Limit
}
foreach ($hhsigns in $hhsignscsv) {
  $FreqShopPrice = $Price - $FreqShopValue
}
Out-Printer -InputObject $hhsignscsv
```

Can anyone tell me why the Math part (`$FreqShopPrice = $Price - $FreqShopValue`) won't put the values into the `$FreqShopPrice` column? I don't get any syntax errors when debugging or running but on the print out the `$FreqShopPrice` is blank instead of containing the value of the subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
$FreqShopPrice = $hhsigns.FreqShopPrice
```

copies the value of the CSV field `FreqShopPrice` into the variable `$FreqShopPrice`.

The statement

```
$FreqShopPrice = $Price - $FreqShopValue
```

updates the variable `$FreqShopPrice` with the difference between the variables `$Price` and `$FreqShopValue`. However, since you filled those variables in a separate loop before the current loop they contain the values from the last record from the CSV.

To actually update the field `FreqShopPrice` in the CSV you need to do it like this:

```
foreach($hhsigns in $hhsignscsv) {
  $hhsigns.FreqShopPrice = $hhsigns.Price - $hhsigns.FreqShopValue
}
```

Remove the other loop. It serves no purpose except burning CPU cycles.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help! I can see now how I was just setting the variable value not actually writing anything to the CSV. I thought that I had to assign the columns to variables so I could perform math with them but I just noticed I wasn't putting the value back somehow. I didn't know I can use $Rowvariable.columnheader to pinpoint a value in the CSV!